# Why user_regs_struct values for execve syscall are 0 and how to fix this issue?

Tags: linux, system-calls, ptrace, execve

I am trying to catpure name of an executable for execve system call using ptrace as -

`long val = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, sizeof(long) * RDI);`

Where `RDI` is the register which holds first argument to `execve`

I was hoping to get some arbitrary number in `val` But, it ended up having `0` all the time.

Comment: How are you stopping the program at the `execve` moment? Are you sure that your tracee is caught at the right moment?

Comment: @MarkSegal I am checking value of `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, sizeof(long) * ORIG_RAX);` and making sure it equals to `__NR_EXECVE` this macro is defined in `asm/unistd_64.h`. I am able to print some text when `execve` is trapped.